# How can I retrieve a unique-to-the-device value?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get unique machine id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004666/get-unique-machine-id)

I want to retrieve a value unique to the device (tablet, laptop, or desktop computer). Does anybody know how to get such a value?

Comment: It seems I've found an answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/62ac2a48-be60-465c-b3b7-bbb736a67a60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the closest is the [ASHWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx).  That value can vary with hardware configuration however, so you may have to parse the ASHWID for various tolerance levels. For example, if a device added a new drive is that the same device or not? probably yes, but one component of the ASHWID would change.