# Fastest way to retrieve hard disk serial and physical MAC address

Tags: c#, security, native, guid

I'm developing a client/server application which needs to assign a unique identifier to every registered client based on hard disk serial number and physical adapter MAC address... but I prefer not to use ManagementObjectSearcher or any WMI solution as they are quite slow. How can I obtain those values using native methods?

Comment: WHat happens if your user changes their HD?

Comment: What if a user has multiple network adapters (wired and wireless)?

Comment: Why is speed relevant for a one-time lookup of two numbers?

Comment: Possibly related: [Get unique machine id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004666/get-unique-machine-id) -- Also, is this for security or just need something unique for the client? Could always use a Guid if it's just for a "signature".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get a unique identifier out of hardware values, you have to keep in mind that is really important to apply always the same method for every registered client. What I mean is that if a machine have multiple HDD, and it's quite common, you will always have to take the serial out of the first one or the last one, for everyone.
Unless you are doing this only for licensing purposes, you also have to implement a tolerance algorithm capable of understanding if a user changed one or more components of his computer.
I'll show you the code I normally use to create unique identifiers out of hardware values... it's maybe a little bit outdated expecially for what concerns 64x support (registry keys and pointers, especially) but it's just to give you an idea. The fingerprint is created out of the first HDD serial, the first adapter MAC address and SMBIOS data using only native methods.

```
public static class HardwareAnalyzer
{
#region Methods: Imports
[DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern Int32 GetAdaptersInfo(IntPtr handle, ref UInt32 size);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern Boolean CloseHandle([In] IntPtr handle);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern Boolean DeviceIoControl([In] IntPtr handle, [In] UInt32 controlCode, [In, Optional] IntPtr bufferIn, [In] UInt32 bufferInSize, [Out, Optional] IntPtr bufferOut, [In] UInt32 bufferOutSize,  [Out] out UInt32 bytesReturned, [In, Out, Optional] IntPtr overlapped);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = false, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr CreateFile([In] String fileName, [In] eFileAccess fileAccess, [In] EFileShare fileShare, [In, Optional] IntPtr fileSecurity, [In] eCreationDisposition creationDisposition, [In] UInt32 flags, [In, Optional] IntPtr handleTemplateFile);
#endregion

#region Methods: Functions
private static String RetrieveDiskSerial()
{
    String serial = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            handle = CreateFile(String.Format("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive{0}", i), (eFileAccess.GenericRead | eFileAccess.GenericWrite), (EFileShare.Read | EFileShare.Write), IntPtr.Zero, eCreationDisposition.OpenExisting, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                serial = RetrieveDiskSerialSmart(handle);

                if (serial.Length == 0)
                    serial = RetrieveDiskSerialStorageQuery(handle);

                if (serial.Length == 0)
                    continue;

                if (!CloseHandle(handle))
                    Console.WriteLine("WARNING: a file handle has not been correctly closed.");

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return serial;
}

private static String RetrieveDiskSerialSmart(IntPtr handle)
{
    IntPtr bufferIn = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(32);
    IntPtr bufferOut = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(24);
    String serial = String.Empty;
    UInt32 bytesReturned = 0;

    try
    {
        if (DeviceIoControl(handle, 0x074080, IntPtr.Zero, 0, bufferOut, 24, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if ((Marshal.ReadInt32(bufferOut, 4) & 4) > 0)
            {
                SCInputParameters parameters = new SCInputParameters();
                bufferOut = Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal(bufferOut, (IntPtr)528);

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(parameters, bufferIn, true);

                if (DeviceIoControl(handle, 0x07C088, bufferIn, 32, bufferOut, 528, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    String serialANSI = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)(bufferOut.ToInt32() + 36), 20);

                    if (serialANSI.Length != 0)
                    {
                        Char[] serialANSICharacters = serialANSI.ToCharArray();

                        for (Int32 i = 0; i <= (serialANSICharacters.Length - 2); i += 2)
                        {
                            Char current = serialANSICharacters[i];

                            serialANSICharacters[i] = serialANSICharacters[(i + 1)];
                            serialANSICharacters[(i + 1)] = current;
                        }

                        serial = new String(serialANSICharacters).Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferIn);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferOut);
    }

    return serial;
}

private static String RetrieveDiskSerialStorageQuery(IntPtr handle)
{
    IntPtr bufferIn = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(12);
    IntPtr bufferOut = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
    StoragePropertyQuery query = new StoragePropertyQuery();
    String serial = String.Empty;
    UInt32 bytesReturned = 0;

    try
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(query, bufferIn, true);

        if (DeviceIoControl(handle, 0x2D1400, bufferIn, 12, bufferOut, 1024, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            Int32 address = bufferOut.ToInt32();
            Int32 offset = Marshal.ReadInt32(bufferOut, 24);

            if (offset != 0)
            {
                String serialANSI = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)(address + offset));

                if (serialANSI.Length != 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                    for (Int32 i = 0; i < serialANSI.Length; i += 4)
                    {
                        for (Int32 j = 1; j >= 0; --j)
                        {
                            Int32 sum = 0;

                            for (Int32 y = 0; y < 2; ++y)
                            {
                                sum *= 16;

                                switch (serialANSI[(i + (j * 2) + y)])
                                {
                                    case '0':
                                        sum += 0;
                                        break;

                                    case '1':
                                        sum += 1;
                                        break;

                                    case '2':
                                        sum += 2;
                                        break;

                                    case '3':
                                        sum += 3;
                                        break;

                                    case '4':
                                        sum += 4;
                                        break;

                                    case '5':
                                        sum += 5;
                                        break;

                                    case '6':
                                        sum += 6;
                                        break;

                                    case '7':
                                        sum += 7;
                                        break;

                                    case '8':
                                        sum += 8;
                                        break;

                                    case '9':
                                        sum += 9;
                                        break;

                                    case 'a':
                                        sum += 10;
                                        break;

                                    case 'b':
                                        sum += 11;
                                        break;

                                    case 'c':
                                        sum += 12;
                                        break;

                                    case 'd':
                                        sum += 13;
                                        break;

                                    case 'e':
                                        sum += 14;
                                        break;

                                    case 'f':
                                        sum += 15;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (sum > 0)
                                builder.Append((Char)sum);
                        }
                    }

                    serial = builder.ToString().Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferIn);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferOut);
    }

    return serial;
}

private static String RetrieveMACAddress()
{
    String address = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        UInt32 size = 0;
        Int32 result = GetAdaptersInfo(IntPtr.Zero, ref size);

        if ((result == 0) || (result == 111))
        {
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)size);
            result = GetAdaptersInfo(buffer, ref size);

            if (result == 0)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    String adapterName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)(buffer.ToInt32() + 8));
                    IntPtr handle = CreateFile(String.Format("\\\\.\\{0}", adapterName), (eFileAccess.GenericRead | eFileAccess.GenericWrite), (EFileShare.Read | EFileShare.Write), IntPtr.Zero, eCreationDisposition.OpenExisting, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

                    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        IntPtr bufferIn = GCHandle.Alloc(0x1010101, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject();
                        IntPtr bufferOut = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(6);
                        UInt32 bytesReturned = 0;

                        try
                        {
                            if (DeviceIoControl(handle, 0x170002, bufferIn, 4, bufferOut, 6, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
                            {
                                String temporaryAddress = String.Empty;

                                for (Int32 i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
                                    temporaryAddress += Marshal.ReadByte(bufferOut, i).ToString("X2") + ((i == 5) ? "" : ":");

                                if (temporaryAddress != "00:00:00:00:00:00")
                                {
                                    address = temporaryAddress;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (!CloseHandle(handle))
                                Console.WriteLine("WARNING: a file handle has not been correctly closed.");

                            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferOut);
                        }
                    }

                    Int32 nextAdapterOffset = Marshal.ReadInt32(buffer);

                    if (nextAdapterOffset != 0)
                        buffer = (IntPtr)nextAdapterOffset;
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return address;
}

private static String RetrieveSMBiosData()
{
    String data = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSMBios\Data", false))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                Byte[] keyData = (Byte[])key.GetValue("SMBiosData");

                if (keyData != null)
                {
                    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
                        keyData = provider.ComputeHash(keyData);

                    for (Int32 i = 0; i < keyData.Length; ++i)
                        data += keyData[i].ToString("X2");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return data;
}

public static String CreateFingerprint()
{
    String serial = RetrieveDiskSerial();
    String address = RetrieveMACAddress();
    String data = RetrieveSMBiosData();

    if ((serial.Length == 0) && (address.Length == 0) && (data.Length == 0))
        return "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000";

    String fingerprint = String.Empty;

    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        Byte[] hash = provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serial + " - " + address + " - " + data));

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            fingerprint += hash[i].ToString("X2");

            if (((i & 1) != 0) && (i != 15))
                fingerprint += "-";
        }
    }

    return fingerprint;
}
#endregion

#region Nesting: Enumerators
public enum eCreationDisposition : uint
{
    New              = 1,
    CreateAlways     = 2,
    OpenExisting     = 3,
    OpenAlways       = 4,
    TruncateExisting = 5
}

[Flags]
public enum eFileAccess : uint
{
    Delete               = 0x00010000,
    ReadControl          = 0x00020000,
    WriteDAC             = 0x00040000,
    WriteOwner           = 0x00080000,
    Synchronize          = 0x00100000,
    AccessSystemSecurity = 0x01000000,
    MaximumAllowed       = 0x02000000,
    GenericAll           = 0x10000000,
    GenericExecute       = 0x20000000,
    GenericWrite         = 0x40000000,
    GenericRead          = 0x80000000
}

[Flags]
public enum EFileShare : uint
{
    None   = 0x00000000,
    Read   = 0x00000001,
    Write  = 0x00000002,
    Delete = 0x00000004
}
#endregion

#region Nesting: Structures
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private class SCInputParameters
{
    private int BufferSize = 528;
    private Byte Features = 0;
    private Byte SectorCount = 1;
    private Byte SectorNumber = 1;
    private Byte LowOrderCylinder = 0;
    private Byte HighOrderCylinder = 0;
    private Byte DriveHead = 160;
    private Byte Command = 236;
    private Byte Reserved = 0;
    private Byte DriveNumber = 0;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    private Byte[] UselessData = new Byte[16];
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private class StoragePropertyQuery
{
    private Int32 PropertyID;
    private Int32 QueryType;
    private Int32 UselessData;
}
#endregion
}
```

You just have to call HardwareAnalyzer.CreateFingerprint() to obtain what you need.

Comment: thanks for the code-snippet. If the client is using VPN, that tends to screw around the MAC addresses a bit, does your tolerance algorithm hold good for such cases?