# Machine Key Generation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, security, key

I have a vb.net product that has a trial version runner embedded. I want the user to be able to click a button to generate a machine specific key/code from his end, if he is interested in purchasing and send that code/key to me to generate an activation key in order to run the full version of the product.

I have been combing stackoverflow for something that can guide me but seem not to get very close answers. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get unique machine id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2004666/11683)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer GSerg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it can be as simple as generating a GUID at the user machine and storing it locally in a license file in a json format .

```
{
"Permissions": [
{
  "Name": "My Sample Application",
  "Description": "Application Description goes here",
  "Entitlements": [
    {
      "ResourceType": "validity",
      "ResourceValue": "2020/12/31"
    },
    {
      "ResourceType": "num_of_users",
      "ResourceValue": "5"
    }
  ],
  "EntitlementKey": [
    {
      "KeySignature": "",

    }
  ]
}
]
```

You can then add your license entitlement to the struture by signing the contents using your private key .

The software on it's side can always validate the license using the public part and can then enforce the entitlement on the  user's system